# Sorting numerically

Tags: sort

I have a file called `data` whose contents are

```
id,col1,col2
0,-0.3479417882673812,0.5664382596767175
1,-0.26800930980980764,0.2952025161991604
2,-0.4159790791116641,-1.3375045524610152
3,-0.7859665489205871,-0.6428101880909471
4,-1.3922759043388822,-1.676262144826317
5,-1.2471867496427498,-0.4912119581361516
6,1.443385383041667,1.6974039491263593
7,-2.058899802821969,2.0607628464079917
8,-0.10641338441541626,0.035929568275064216
9,-0.517273684861199,-0.6184800988804992
10,-0.9934859021679552,1.0577312348984502
11,0.5923834706792905,-0.6693757541250825
12,0.8657741917554445,-0.6876271057571398
13,-1.2061097548360489,-0.7402582563022937
14,0.78768021182158,-0.38607117005262315
```

Sorting numerically (`-n`) on the first column gives

```
$ sort -nk1 -t"," data
0,-0.3479417882673812,0.5664382596767175
id,col1,col2
1,-0.26800930980980764,0.2952025161991604
2,-0.4159790791116641,-1.3375045524610152
3,-0.7859665489205871,-0.6428101880909471
4,-1.3922759043388822,-1.676262144826317
5,-1.2471867496427498,-0.4912119581361516
7,-2.058899802821969,2.0607628464079917
8,-0.10641338441541626,0.035929568275064216
9,-0.517273684861199,-0.6184800988804992
10,-0.9934859021679552,1.0577312348984502
13,-1.2061097548360489,-0.7402582563022937
6,1.443385383041667,1.6974039491263593
11,0.5923834706792905,-0.6693757541250825
12,0.8657741917554445,-0.6876271057571398
14,0.78768021182158,-0.38607117005262315
```

This absolutely bizarre to me. I read in the man page that `-n` is supposed to be numerical sort. Why would `id` be placed in-between numbers? How is it that `10` is larger than `9`, but smaller than `6`, all the while `11` being greater than them all?

The `-g` seems to work as I want (and as I think is natural), but this `-n` option totally escapes me. What's this about? I think it can be related to locale, but once I specify the delimiter as being `,`, I don't think that would explain it.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

### TL;DR

Use `sort -nk1,1 -t,` or otherwise with `-k1` you're sorting on the full line where `,` is discarded in  numbers as it's interpreted as a thousand separator.

### Details

In English language locales, `,` is the thousand separator, which `sort` ignores in the integer part of numbers.

In other words, in an English language locale, or any locale where `,` is a thousand separator (see the output of `locale thousands_sep`), when `sort -n` sees `11,000,000` it doesn't see the `11` number followed by some ignored garbage, but the `11000000` number. Similarly `11,0` is not `11` but `110`.

Now (and that's something many people trip on), `-k1` defines a key that starts with the first field, but as you didn't specify where it stops, ends at the end of the line, so the sort key is the full line, which is the default.

So `sort -nk1 -t,` is exactly the same as `sort -n`.

With `,` ignored as a thousand separator, on your input `sort` is actually sorting these numbers:

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
61.4433853830416671
7
8
9
10
110.5923834706792905
120.8657741917554445
13
140.78768021182158
```

So it's not `6` vs `10` vs `11`, but `61.4433853830416671` vs `10` vs `110.5923834706792905`.

Here, you want:

```
sort -nk1,1 -t,
```

To sort on the first `,`-delimited field only. `-k1,1` defines a sort key that starts at the start of the first field and ends at the end of the first field.

You can also use `sort -n` in the C locale where `,` is neither the decimal radix nor the thousand separator (and `.` is the decimal radix):

```
LC_ALL=C sort -n
```

`sort -g` works differently because `sort` then uses [`strtold()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strtod.html) to interpret the key as a number and `strtold()` doesn't recognise thousands separators.

As far as the `id` header line is concerned, in a numeric comparison, that `id...` is interpreted as `0` as there's no number to be seen there. It sorts after the line that starts with `0` because when two records sort the same (here with `-n` in a numeric comparison) `sort` does a *last resort comparison* which is a *lexical* comparison of the full line (and `0` sorts before `i`).

With some `sort` implementations, that *last resort comparison* can be disabled with `-s`. Here `LC_ALL=C sort -sn` would put the `id` line first, but that's only because there are no negative keys in the input (`id` (which again numerically is 0) would still sort after `-1`). If you want to exclude the first line from the sorting, you can do:

```
(head -n1; LC_ALL=C sort -n) < file
```

Comment: Thanks. `sort -t, -n -k1,1` is not working for me, it's placing `0` above `id`. Also, does your answer explain why `10` is larger than `9`, but smaller than `6`, all the while `11` being greater than them all? It's genuine question, I'm not able to answer this myself from reading your answer.

Comment: @user347221, see if the edit makes it any clearer.

Comment: Why do you talk so much about the thousands separator? There's nothing in the question that suggests that they expected it to be part of the number. They have `-t","` to use it as the field delimiter.

Comment: Where is `61.4433853830416671` in the input file? I see `6,1.443385383041667,1.6974039491263593`.

Comment: Is the actual problem just that they put `-t","` after the key specification instead of before it?

Comment: @Barmar, they have `-t,` but sort on the full line (`-k1` which is superflous as that's the default) instead of the first field (`-k1,1`). `6,1.443385383041667` is interpreted by `sort -n` as `61.4433853830416671` because that `,` thousand separator is ignored.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Thank you, this is great. unix.SE is eons beyond other SE sites. People actually help here. I've had great experiences with many of the users here. Gilles, Kusalananda, Stephen, terdon to name a few. Thank you all.

Comment: What is the syntax to get it to sort on the second and third columns, then on the fifth and stop here?

Comment: For those looking to an answer to my question in the comment above. Here it is: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/78925/how-to-sort-by-multiple-columns?rq=1